Is it possible to use Riverpod ref after an async operation, during which the widget may be disposed?
I want to essentially do something like this:
onTap: () async {
  // await the result of an async operation
  final result = await someLongDatabaseGet(currentStateOfWidget);
  // some logic
  final processedResult = process(result);
  // add the processed result to backend using Riverpod
  ref.read(myControllerProvider.notifier).addToBackend(processedResult);
}

The problem is, the user may exit this screen during the long database get. I would love for there to be some way that even if the user exits this screen to do other things in the app, all the logic still chugs along in the background and eventually adds the processed result to the backend. But if the user exits the screen the widget is disposed and thus the ref cannot be used in that last line. Is there a way to make this work?

Move all the work to a notifier method instead. That way you only need to call the notifier method in a single line.

The short answer Is to male something like :
If (context.kounted) .....
Before calling ref.read(...)
But i suggest you to define mycontrollerProvider as singleton using
@Riverpod(keepAlive:true)
And It would never be disposed.
I thino It Is correct because It Is a service not related to the widget Life cycle
